# Cannot playback HLS Live playlist correctly

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8

I've got an m3u8 playlist that is constantly being updated as soon as new .ts segments are written for live streaming. However, playing it back seems to not work correctly. It would play the video of the m3u8 playlist for about 15-20 seconds then it would stop and show a loading indicator.

Both the .ts files and .m3u8 playlist are uploaded and updated on S3.

Here's my playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:20
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live20.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live21.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live22.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live23.ts
#EXTINF:7.200000,
live24.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live25.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live26.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live27.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live28.ts
#EXTINF:4.800000,
live29.ts
```

Anyone know what the issue is here?

Comment: If everything is as you describe, then it works fine. Nobody can help you unless you provide a way to reproduce, or more information.

Comment: Thanks @szatmary for the feedback. I'll try and get a working example up and running.